# Redirect from a method in a React component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The  `<Redirect>` tag can be used, to [redirect to another route from within React render method.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) How can I do the same within a React component method like ?
`componentDidMount` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can import history and use history.push to programatically navigate your React Router project in lifecycle methods or methods.

[React-Router Docs - History](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)